# My system cant access hard drive HP

Tags: command-line

I have an HP Pavilion that was running windows 8.  I tried to turn it on one day and it wouldnt load windows.  The system cant even see my hard drive for Windows recovery.

I know nothing about ubuntu or linux.  But I heard I can possibly fix it from outside operating system. My question is how do I get ubuntu to get to an interface to access my harddrive.  or from the command prompt how I can fix the harddrive.  I see the rescue broken system mode.  while that process was going it wanted to install the root directory but ran into an issue.  I chose the /dev/sda1 method when the enter rescue mode popped up.  then I got the mount failed error.  What to do next?  I CHOSE do not use a root file.  Now I will select in rescue operations what?  Can you please help me recover my system.

Comment: Broken/crashing/crashed HD?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to rescue your data, proceed this way:

Start Ubuntu from USB or DVD. It will run a fully working live system. No need to install or modify any partition!
The rescue system is meant to repair Ubuntu. not Windows.

After it has booted up, you can start the file manager. It should show your harddrive and you will be able to browse it's content.
If it's not showing here, you should install it into another pc or buy a usb-s-ata connector.